# Hey, Guys I am having issues with browser sync downloading

Tags: javascript, windows, npm, browser-sync

I am a beginner trying to get everything together. I can not seem to get the browser sync to download for anything. I have node .js downloaded it comes up on the command I have git and visual studio. When I try to download it I keep getting this error every time. "32 packages need funding". Any tips to help me will be appreciated. Thank you.

I have downloaded and updated all the software. I added visual studio as well. I have all syncing on. What am I missing?

Comment: `When I try to download it I keep getting this error every time. "32 packages need funding"` That's not an error, it's just projects who have made it known they would be amenable to donations. You can donate if you like, or ignore the message like most people do.